# Don't understand why my function can't be called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to make a little text based rpg with **python**.
And the first thing that I want to make is an input to **equip** *armor* or *weapons*.

```
def find_armor(x):
    if x=="bad armor":
        armor=bad_armor
    if x=="good armor":
        armor=good_armor

##item
armor=[0,0]
bad_armor=["bad armor",300]
good_armor=["good armor", 500]

##choose
option1,option2=input(">").split(" ",1)
if option1=="equip":
    find_armor(option2)

##ui
armor_name=armor[0]
armor_point=armor[1]
print("your armor:",armor_name,armor_point)
```

**So here is the problem**:

my function `find_armor` is not calling whatever I enter.

If my first word is "*equip*" the output is always: `your armor: 0 0`

Comment: If you're creating a game in python, which consists on *saving state* of any form (like: Character is holding armor), I strongly encourage using python classes for the task. It will probably save you lot of headache and help you in your coding journey later on, too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a function, variables change with local scope. Then use `global armor` before. And fixing the bad indentation:

```
def find_armor(x):
  global armor
  if x=="bad armor":
    global bad_armor
    armor=bad_armor
  elif x=="good armor":
    global good_armor
    armor=good_armor
```

Comment: globals might be handy for some tasks, but in this one I would rather pass in an instance of some sort of `Character` class, or even a dictionary. As Zen of Python says: Explicit is better than implicit (magical globals are not very explicit, and can lead code to be hard to read later on)